# Passing diffrent time slots in same field Django Rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to send 3 diffrent time slots in a field ,But do not getting the diffrent slots,but getting error-->"message": "JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 3 column 9 (char 27)",

```
models.py
class Slot(models.Model):
    time=models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.time)


views.py
class Available(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def create(self, request):
        try:
            data=request.data
            timings=data.get('schedule')
            for i in range(3):
                time_obj=Slot()
                time_obj.time=timings[i]['time']
                time_obj.save()
            return Response({"message":"Data delivered","success": True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as error:
            traceback.print_exc()
            return Response({"message": str(error), "success": False}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

postman response

{
    "schedule":{
        {
            "time":"12:00"
        },
        {
            "time":"12:10"
        },
        {
            "time":"15:00"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like the data sent is not valid JSON it should be something like

```json
{
    "schedule":[
        {
            "time":"12:00"
        },
        {
            "time":"12:10"
        },
        {
            "time":"15:00"
        }
    ]
}
```